# How to add profiling to unit test cases in Teamcity?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, profiling, teamcity, teamcity-7.1

Is it possible to add memory/performance profiling of unit tests as a team city build step?

I am specifically interested in doing it for our .Net apps (test cases are written in NUnit). Any elaboration on this will be highly appreciated.

Teamcity version is "TeamCity Enterprise 7.1.2 (build 24170)"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, TeamCity does not support profiling .Net apps yet. At least not in a direct way.

There is an open feature request [TW-20190](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-20190) planning to integrate [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) (a .Net profiler made also by JetBrains) in Teamcity.

But dotTrace [can be called from command line](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/09/25/profiling-from-the-command-line-using-dottrace-performance/), so you can write MSBuild/NAnt script to execute dotTrace. The problem is about how to display the profiling results. In "General Settings" page of your build config, you can point [artifacts path](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-ArtifactPaths) to the dotTrace result folder, so that teamcity will publish the profiling results as artifacts for you to download.

Comment: Thanks Jifeng for your answer and the links. I will try your suggestions.